# Visual studio code map equivalent in XCode

Tags: xcode, code-map

Has anyone come across any code map Visual Studio alternative for XCode to visualize the ObjC code ? I tried OmniGraffle but it wasn't that easy to use and gave up in the end.
I am surprised XCode did not make any investment in this similar to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There's no graphical equivalent. You can bring up all the callers or callees of a particular method, including the call stack, and you can examine graphically the in memory object dependencies. That's about the most you can do.